# how to optimize linq query where Data is coming from two different databases?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Summary : I have to show the list of visits into the restaurant in current Date for this i have query two different databases from database 1 i have two tables ( TH_Order and GS_booking ) and from 2nd database (CustomerFeedback) 
What i am doing rite now is

```
IEnumerable<ModelEngro.TH_Order> th_Order = _EntitiesEngro.TH_Order;
IEnumerable<ModelEngro.GS_Booking> Booking = _EntitiesEngro.GS_Booking.Where(x => x.Session_ID == NSession);
if (Dated != null)
    Booking = Booking.Where(x => x.Date.Date == Dated.ConvertToDate().Date);

IEnumerable<CustomerFeedback> CustomerFeedbacks = _EntitiesCRM.CustomerFeedbacks;

IEnumerable<ModelEngro.TH_Order> th_order = (from o in th_Order 
join b in Booking on o.Booking_id equals b.ID
join c in CustomerFeedbacks on o.Booking_id equals c.BookingID.ConvertToInt() into cFouter
from cf in cFouter.DefaultIfEmpty()
where cf == null
orderby b.Date descending
select new
{
     Booking_id = o.Booking_id,
     Bill_No = o.Bill_No,
     Sales_Tax = o.Sales_Tax,
     AdultOnTable = o.AdultOnTable,                                     
     ChildOnTable = o.ChildOnTable,
     Discount = o.Discount,
     Remarks = o.Remarks,
     ContectPerson = b.Contact_person
}).Select(x => new ModelEngro.TH_Order
{
     Booking_id = x.Booking_id,
     Bill_No = x.Bill_No,
     ales_Tax = x.Sales_Tax,
     AdultOnTable = x.AdultOnTable,
     ChildOnTable = x.ChildOnTable,
     Discount = x.Discount,
     Remarks = x.Remarks,
     ContectPerson = x.ContectPerson
});
```

All of these tables have minimum 100K records and this Query takes 40-50 sec on Application server I want to optimize this query any help can be appreciated.

Comment: And i have to get only recorde of current day.

Comment: I think it's a question for codereview stackexchange website. There they suggest how to improve your working code.

Comment: If your databases are on the same server you can build a [sql query that joins them](http://forums.asp.net/t/1254974.aspx?How+to+join+tables+from+different+databases+in+SQL+select+statement+) and get your data from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options.

1.Try using stored procedure

```
var result = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<type>("GetDataProc @param1", param1)
                .ToList();
```

But if you need a quick work around then you can just create index on your related columns.

2.Creating index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing your computation on the level of your database via Stored Procedure and return the desired result to your solution.
You can save a lot of time by having your database server doing the computation.

Answer (score 0):

[Add the second server as a linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) object in the first server, assuming this is MSSQL.

Once the server object is added, you will need to create local views querying the remote server. For example, let's say SQL1 is your local server and SQL2 is a remote server. In Management Studio, on SQL1, you add a linked server connection to SQL2. Then you need to go around a limitation with Entity Framework, which doesn't support linked servers directly. Create a view for each data set you will need from SQL2 on SQL1, and then use EF to query SQL1 exclusively. SQL Server will manage the cross-database and cross-server queries server-side. This is far more flexible than creating stored procedures for all your cross-server queries. If SQL2 supports change notification the views also provide you with a passive caching mechanism, greatly reducing the back and forth chatter between both servers. This entirely bypasses the cross-context query limitation of EF.

Entity Framework (prior to V6, I think they added support for multiple databases in the same context in 6.1) requires a separate context for each database, which forces queries that require both contexts to be realized locally, reducing performance. Client has to query both servers separately and then combine the results. With linked servers and views, the client queries the first server, and the server operates under a single context.

If both databases are on the same server, the same strategy works too, just without linked server. Create views querying your second database in your first database.